# Why ,when executing mstsc.exe (remote desktop) from c# , the process HasExited = true and doesnt have MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, remote-desktop, rdp

My main goal is to open remote desktop and release it back when the remote session is ended.
I am tryng to host Mstsc.exe in winform application , so I will manage the closing of the process and send release command to the remote PC.
this can be done by batch file:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console)
```

The c# code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Add the cratential of the remote PC

```
        Process p = Process.Start(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Windows\system32\cmdkey.exe "), string.Format(" /generic:TERMSRV/{0} /user:{1} /pass:{2}", host, userName, password));
```

Open remote desktop:

```
        Process mainP = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\mstsc.exe ", (" /v " + host));
        mainP.Exited += P_Exited;
        while (mainP.MainWindowHandle ==null || mainP.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            //mainP.Refresh();

        }
        Console.WriteLine(mainP.MainWindowHandle);
        SetParent(mainP.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
```

MainWindowHandle  is always zero , If I refresh the process I get exceptions.
mainP.HasExited is true altought mstsc is open.
How can I get MainWindowHandle  of MSTSC.exe  ?

Thanks

Comment: I tested this on my machine and found that mstsc.exe launches a separate process (different PID) when you use the /v switch and the original process terminates. You will need to find the new process before you can get its main window handle.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683): "it is technically legal.

It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws... they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree. (I often see this question in the context of somebody who wants to grab a window belonging to another process and forcibly graft it into their own process..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Remote Desktop client seems to be implemented in such a way that, when launched using command-line arguments, it will process the arguments, start a separate process (if the arguments are valid) and then terminate the original process.

This means that you will need a `Process` instance that represents the new process in order to get the handle to its main window.

Adding to your original code:

```
Process mainP = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\mstsc.exe ", (" /v " + "CLSERVER"));
mainP.WaitForExit();
mainP.Dispose();
Process otherP;
while ((otherP = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc").FirstOrDefault()) == null) {
    Thread.Sleep(20);
}
otherP.Exited += P_Exited;
while (otherP.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
    Thread.Sleep(20);
}
Console.WriteLine(otherP.MainWindowHandle);
SetParent(otherP.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
```

I was able to successfully get the handle when using the above code, however it does not account for multiple instances of mstsc.exe - if you need to distinguish between them, you will need to examine the processes more closely (maybe look at `MainWindowTitle`?).